# List of 2D shape in python used as parameter in imbalanced learn SMOTE?

Tags: python, oversampling

I am trying to perform an oversampling of my dataset in a multi-regression problem. For the oversampling I am using the imblearn.over_sampling library and the SMOTE teqnique.

The features are weapons shape (size,16) and maps shape (size,20,20,7).
The targets are of shape (size,16).

I am performing a train-test split where train_x and train_y are extracted

```
train_x = [weapons[:train_size, :], maps[:train_size, :]]
train_y = targets[:train_size]
```

Then using SMOTE :

```
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
train_x_oversampled, train_y_oversampled = sm.fit_sample(train_x, train_y)
```

But I get the error **"ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (280000,16) into shape (280000)"**

I have tried to convert the list to ndarray using np.asarray but the issue still remains.

Any thoughs on the matter ?